# Deploying Delphi XE 8 APP to iOS(iPhone)

Tags: iphone, delphi, delphi-xe8

I have the following environment:
**- Windows 7 64 bits
-Delphi XE8
-Oracle Virtual Box with Mountain Lion
-Google Developer Account
-Apple Developer Account**

I already developed an APP for Android and it works fine and is already published on Google Play.

What I want now is to publish this APP to iOS(iPhone).

I can also run the application using the Iphone Emulator on the Virtual Box with Mountain Lion and the APP works fine on the emulator.

What I want now is the following:

- Publish this APP on my device iPhone **OR**
- Publish the APP on Play Store.

I saw several videos on Youtube showing tips, saying that I have to create certificates and etc. I did all these stuff at Apple Website and also ItunesConnect, but my problem is at Delphi XE 8. When I try to setup the Targe for Iphone Simnulator works fine, you can see in the image below that shows the options: IPAD, IPHONE and IPHONE 5

[image]

The problem is when I select the Iphone Device, Delphi does not show any options for selection:

[image]

Can someone give a tip here?

Answer (score 0):

Read Embarcadero's documentation, it answers all of your questions.

[iOS Mobile Application Development](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/IOS_Mobile_Application_Development)

[Running Your iOS Application on the iOS Simulator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Running_Your_iOS_Application_on_the_iOS_Simulator)

[Running Your iOS Application on an iOS Device](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Running_Your_iOS_Application_on_an_iOS_Device)

[Preparing an iOS Application for Deployment](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Preparing_an_iOS_Application_for_Deployment)

[Deploying Your iOS Application for Ad hoc Distribution](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Deploying_Your_iOS_Application_for_Ad_hoc_Distribution)

[Deploying Your iOS Application for Submission to the App Store](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Deploying_Your_iOS_Application_for_Submission_to_the_App_Store)

[Submitting Your App to the App Store (iOS)](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Submitting_Your_App_to_the_App_Store_(iOS))

Comment: Remy, I already ready the documentation and to be honest is not very clear, my problem is when I try to setup the target for iOS Device 64 bits the list of devices is empty, does not show anything.

Comment: The documentation gives you step-by-step instructions on how to set everything up. What exactly is not clear about it? The drop-down list you are pointing out is populated with iOS devices that you have physically connected to the USB ports of your OSX system, and PAServer is running on OSX so the IDE can connect to it to communicate with the devices. Are you doing that? Do you have Provisioning configured? Dod you read the [Running Your iOS Application on an iOS Device](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE8/en/Running_Your_iOS_Application_on_an_iOS_Device) documentation?